# website looks different when live

Tags: css, html

so i don't think my website is picking up the css as when i make it live, the content is there but the style is not. The background is black when it should be white, the font isnt taking effect & the nav isnt showing either. I have done 2 sites the same way only difference is i have uploaded the site to a HTDOCS folder rather than a public_html as this what the hosting said to do...

[this is what it looks like live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2j3s.jpg)

[but should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xbei.jpg)

HEAD OF INDEX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- PAGE TITLE -->
    <title>Peacehaven Golf & Fitness</title>
    <!-- MAKE IT RESPONSIVE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- SEO -->
    <meta name="description" content=peacehavengolfcourse">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- STYLES -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Comment: is there any error message in the navigator's console ?

Comment: Have you uploaded to HTCDOCS all resource folders too ??

Comment: in filezilla ? no it says directory listing successful

Comment: are you sure you fully replicated the site structure on the production server? All the files are at the right place?

Comment: What's the error message shown ! Like 401/403 while trying to load the resource

Comment: Check the `Network` tab in developer console to see if any resources are'nt loaded.

Comment: If you're using "https" in the url to access the website, could you try with "http" instead? Any change?

Comment: @SaciBasaran "directory listing" means that filezilla has managed to open a folder on the remote server and to list the files and subfolder that are eventually there. You have to compare left and right side of the FTP client to see if what is on the left (dev server) is also on the right (prod server). Align the two and you will fix your issue

Comment: ive moved all the resources folders yea, ive uploaded everything that i have been using when testing it locally. There are no error messages

Comment: peacehaven golf and fitness site is looking ok to me (in Chrome) assuming you are updating the live site.

Comment: left hand side & right hand side are exactly the same

Comment: looking at the pics you sent it doesn't seems to me. Provide some code and a link to the live site

Comment: is it not black? with big text & everything out of line? im using chrome also but what im seeing isnt right :(

Comment: http://www.peacehavengc.com

Comment: looks mainly fine to me matey  - bigslideshow at the top, black bar with phone number and email at the very top, white page. Green, blue and burgandy features lower down (although the burgandy one is being cut off)

Comment: open your dev tools then right click on the refresh button and choose empty cache and hard reload.

Comment: Access it on Incognito window to avoid caching (Cmd + Shift + N)

Comment: (Once you get to see it, you need to fix the burgandy feature panel on medium-sized windows - it gets cropped)

Comment: @Alain1405 yes, that's it. The website shows pretty fine here too.  Saci you're viewing the old cache. CTRL+F5 or rather CTRL+SHIFT+N

Comment: That's it @Alain1405 I just checked the live website & every think works fine. it should be a cache issue

Comment: yay what a fool i am thanks guys!! u saved me my job haha no joking but thanks so nice to know i can get help so quick!

Comment: i shall sort the burgundy bit thanks Jon

Comment: you are including the bootstrap css file but are not utilising the main bootstrap styles for assisting with responsive design.  I would advise going to read about it - might help you deal with the resize issues.  Although you might be able to add to your media queries area to fix for now.

Comment: ok Jon will do thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that CSS is there, it may be a cache issue. The old assets are cached by your browser and the new assets are not loaded.

To test, load the website in incognito mode, and the browser won't cache/load the cache.

Mac:

```
Cmd + Shift + N
```

Windows/Linux:

```
Ctrl + Shift + N
```

Comment: According to this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011274/website-looks-different-when-live?noredirect=1#comment53846892_33011274 this should answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

hi your site is working but can you change this code line 10:
 `<meta name="description" content=peacehavengolfcourse">`

to
`<meta name="description" content="peacehavengolfcourse">`
and remove line 38 and 40 `</li> </ul>`
add line 309 `<footer>`
You have syntax errors...